# GoJS exporting file as DXF

Tags: javascript, svg, gojs, dxf

I am working on simple app where I need to export my diagram as SVG and DXF. 
I see that GoJS offers exporting diagram to SVG extension however there is nothing mentioned about DXF files.

I've tried to also to export the diagram to SVG and then tried to convert it to DXF via external tools like Inkscape or other tools however this does not seem to work.

I see that there is also library called Maker.JS which offers export to DXF.

None of these solution work because SVG generated by GoJS creates different code of svg under the hood.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the GoJS SVG code as it is being created via the `elementFinished` property of `makeSVG`.

There are some samples that make use of this property, such as: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/svgDataUrl.html

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for response but modification od what? Of xml code inside svg?

Comment: Modification of the outputted SVG from GoJS, in case you need to change it to make it conform to DXF. It allows you to change what gets constructed for SVG output.